# Display author's page without posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, author

There are some similar questions in the internet, but not fit my situation...

I have a website with a list of pages for multiple authors, and there is a blog which every author could post articles.

Problem is when a new author (ex. author=2) register but haven't posted any post, it will always directs to author=1(admin) page even if I type author=2 on the website link when I eager to see the author's profile page.

Most of similar questions are directing to a blank or 404 page, but for my situation it directs to the admin author's  page which is not the right one.

I make this website for a client, but it's awkward to say you should have post first in order to see your profile page...so I am wondering is there any solution for this problem? Thanks in advance!!

---

2015/11/17 update

Thank you Simon for your reply! I still have no idea of what's wrong in the code.  I think the problem should be the way I call fields in author.php, since the url link is the right author ID.  I tried to paste some lines from author.php, could you please advise if there's anything wrong?

Basically I used ACF to create fields, and below are some examples that I called links, title, telphone, email, intro...

```
<div class="service_box">
  <div class="sns">
       <ul>
         <li class="fb"><a href="<?php $user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID'); the_field('fb_link', 'user_'.$user_id); ?>" target="_blank">facebook</a></li> 
         <li class="in"><a href="<?php $user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID'); the_field('in_link', 'user_'.$user_id); ?>" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a></li> 
       </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
     <h4><?php $user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID'); the_field('lawyer_title_en', 'user_'.$user_id); ?></h4>
     <h2><?php the_author(); ?> <?php $user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID'); the_field('lawyer_en_name', 'user_'.$user_id); ?></h2>
     <span>Tel</span> <?php $user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID'); the_field('lawyer_tel', 'user_'.$user_id); ?>
     <span>Mail</span> <a href="mailto:<?php $user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID'); the_field('lawyer_email', 'user_'.$user_id); ?>"><?php $user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID'); the_field('lawyer_email', 'user_'.$user_id); ?></a>
     <div class="service_quote"><?php $user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID'); the_field('lawyer_brief_en', 'user_'.$user_id); ?></div>
     <?php $user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID'); the_field('lawyer_intro_en', 'user_'.$user_id); ?>
   </div>
```

Comment: Do you have an author.php template page?

Comment: Yes I have author.php template, the list of authors' pages will show by this template.

Comment: The default template as per https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates should just show "No posts by this author" it should not redirect. If your code is different than this, can you please paste it into your questions, cheers.

Comment: Actually I found this problem when I was applying WPML plugin.  Both author and blog post have pages in multiple languages, but I found when the author has post in Chinese blog page, his profile page in Chinese could be shown.  But in English page if he doesn't have any post yet it will direct to the wrong author's page.

Comment: Thank you Simon for your quick anwser, but sorry I'm not using computer now since it's midnight here in Aisa...I will check my code tomorrow to see if I could find any clue, thanks a lot!!